# Why did the upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 ruin my system?

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, when I log in, everything is ruined. It's all black, blank white icons, blank black icons on the start menu, and well, nothing works. If I open up Chromium, it looks as though it's in high contrast mode.

Is this a bug? Any ideas what could have happened? Can I get 11.10 back?

Some photos (can't connect to network in Ubuntu so I had to take pictures with phone):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dwKl.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4nA3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNFje.jpg

Comment: Can you post some screenshots ?

Comment: IIRC librsvg is dead , I've discovered this multiple times on Gentoo linux , good luck ;-P On gentoo you could just rebuild librsvg ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot go back to 11.10 easily and even if you do , it might cause more issues. Better solution is to fix what went wrong. As a first step can you try resetting unity to default values

```
unity --reset

unity --reset-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

The bad look in Chromium is most likely caused by librsvg.

I'm discovered this problem multiple times in Gentoo Linux , rebuild of librsvg usually will solve this problem.

But on Ubuntu , I guess you just need to `wait for package updates.`

Don't worry , that'll be fixed easily.